# Eloquent: Incorrect column in join statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I’m attempting to join the `perspectives` table to the `offers` table based partly on the authenticated organization id. However, Eloquent keeps trying to join on a column name of `"2"` rather than a value of `2`. *This seems to be primarily an issue of context.*

What, pray tell, is the solution?

**Ye Olde Scope**

```php
public function scopeReceived($query)
{
  return $query
    ->where('recipient_id', Auth::user()->organization_id)
    ->join('perspectives', function ($join) {
      $join
        ->on('perspectives.organization_id', '=', Auth::user()->organization_id)
        ->on('perspectives.offer_id', '=', 'offers.id');
    });
}
```

**Ye Olde Error**

```
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 'on clause',
```

**Ye Olde Query Statement**

```sql
SELECT * FROM `offers`
INNER JOIN `perspectives`
    ON `perspectives`.`organization_id` = `2`
    AND `perspectives`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding the third parameter(constant) on your join-on clause with `DB::raw()` could solve the problem.

```
->on('perspectives.organization_id', '=', DB::raw(Auth::user()->organization_id))
```